# iCloud delete and remove device and photos

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, password, screen-lock

Inexplicably I wasn't able to enter my 4 digit password on my iPhone anymore. I tried so many times that my iPhone was deactivated.
I powered off my iPhone and restarted it, but no chance.
Afterwards I asked to delete my iPhone from iCloud.com, but first I requested to erase the phone.
What happens to my iPhone if I've erase my iPhone via iCloud ("Find my Phone") and afterwards I also delete my iPhone from my iCloud account?. Does the request to delete my iPhone still apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the iPhone will still be erased - when you start your iPhone you'll be asked to set it up again as a new one.

EDIT:
It also described on Apple's Support page: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306

> **Erase using Find my iPhone**
>
> If you [enabled Find My iPhone through iCloud](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2697), you can use it to erase your device.
>
> 1. Go to [icloud.com/find](https://www.icloud.com/find).
> 2. If prompted, sign in with your [Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/).
> 3. Click All Devices at the top of your browser window.
> 4. Select the device you want to erase.
> 5. Click Erase [device] to erase your device and its passcode.
> 6. Now you can either [restore from a backup](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204184) or [set up as new](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202033).

Answer (score 0):

When deactivated because of too many passcode attempts, you can also:

Erase it via iTunes:

> 1. Connect your device to the computer you synced with.
> 2. Open iTunes. If asked for a passcode, try another computer you've synced with, or use recovery mode.
> 3. Wait for iTunes to sync your device and make a backup. If it doesn't, learn what to do.
> 4. Once the sync and backup have finished, click Restore [your device].
> 5. When you reach the Set Up screen while restoring your iOS device, tap Restore from iTunes backup.
> 6. Select your device in iTunes. Look at the date and size of each backup and pick the most relevant one.

And via recovery mode:

> 1. Connect your iOS device to your computer and open iTunes. If you don't have a computer, borrow one from a friend, or go to an Apple Retail Store or Apple Authorized Service Provider.
> 2. While your device is connected, force restart it: Press and hold the Sleep/Wake and Home buttons at the same time. Don't let go when you see the Apple logo — keep holding until you see the recovery mode screen.
> 3. When you see the option to Restore or Update, choose Restore.
>      iTunes will download software for your device. If it takes more than 15 minutes, your device will exit recovery mode and you'll need to repeat steps 2 and 3.
> 4. Wait for the process to finish. Then you can set up and use your device.

Please see this support page for more info, useful links and images describing the process: [If you forgot the passcode for your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch, or your device is disabled](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306)